# How to: Google Play style horizontal RecyclerView with parallax background?

Tags: android

I am trying to determine how the Google Play app has implemented a horizontal list whereby the background slides along with the list items.

I have created a video to show this in action: https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/AccurateQuerulousArmadillo

Is this a feature of the support libraries or has Google used a custom implementation to achieve this?

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help https://github.com/sickterror/gplayrecyclerview
Project that i created. It's not perfect but it is a starting point.

Comment: Post the relevant code in your answer, because links will break over time.